# Getting all security groups on EC2 via ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

so I am running ansible against EC2. I need to filter the security groups by their tags. My approach was to get all the security groups and parse them for the required tags, but I am unable to get all the security groups that are present. 
Is there a way to either get all the security groups or filter a security group based on a tag and get it's ID?

Answer (score 0):

you could use aws command line interface to fetch security group info and add filters to choose specific security groups. for example, if i wanted to fetch all security groups that were tagged with a tag *value* of 'Production', this works:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=tag-value,Values=Production
```

using the command line like this requires that you've configured the command line with your specific AWS credentials (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Ansible > 2.3 then use [ec2_group_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_group_facts_module.html#ec2-group-facts-module)

You should be able to filter the sections you want either using the filters option in the module or by using a when statement in the Ansible.